# SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection. Speech Command App

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech, user32

In my speech command app, I am loading files from an external source, processing that data and loading them into a list of possible commands for execution

When I run the app, I get the message in the console

```
Main.exe Information: 0: SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection.
```

I tried solutions such as adding

```
gram.Culture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")
```

I think this is either outdated or does not work on this type of WPF application

Any tips?

Code:

```
{
            InitializeComponent();




        }
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        PromptBuilder builder = new PromptBuilder();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine recog = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        private System.Windows.Input.Key k;
        private int vkey;
        private Choices cmd;

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            b1.IsEnabled = false;
            Choices list = new Choices();
            cmd = Singleton.getInstance().getChoices();
            list.Add(new string[] { "hello", "test", "it works", "sup", "windows", "grenade" });
            Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(cmd));

            try
            {
                recog.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                recog.LoadGrammar(gr);
                recog.SpeechRecognized += Recog_SpeechRecognized;
                recog.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                recog.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            }

            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The message 'SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection.' is information only. To resolve same issue in my case, I needed to go to Control Panel -> Speech Recognition -> Start Speech Recognition to check if the computer was actually getting audio from my microphone.